# loading a new page after a short pause/delay using javascript

Tags: javascript

Am very new to javascript and am trying to simulate a simple animation where I want to load a html page which has the canvas that has some figures and then wait for 3 seconds and load another set of figures on top of the existing ones for it to look like a simuation. I have tried using the setTimeout but that just doesn't kick in after all the iterations are over. Was wondering if there is anything special that needs to be taken into account with canvas?

Thanks!

Comment: <canvas id="myCanvas" width="635" height="430" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>
window.onload = draw;
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var c1 = 20;
 var r1 = 20;
 c.fillStyle = "orange";
              c.fillStyle = "black";
            c.fillRect(c1, r1, 150, 100);
// wait for 3 seconds and then load the yellow box
 setInterval(function() {
    }, 3000);
              c.fillStyle = "yellow";
            c.fillRect(c1, r1, 150, 100);
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function of javascript

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //do something special
  }, 3000);
```

In this 3000 is 3000 milliseconds , so can increase or decrease it.

Comment: Thanks Manu, I have tried that but it just doesn't pause. :( It runs through all the fillRect (s) and only after that it pauses.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a variable **displayRects** and do in draw function `if (displayRects)  {
//draw rects
}`

And before on document load do

```
setTimeout(function(){displayRects = true},3000);
```

Comment: Tried this, but didn't really help much:<script>

var displayRects = true;
setTimeout(function(){displayRects = true},3000)
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {

if (displayRects){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var interV;
 var c1 = 20;
 var r1 = 20;

        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.fillRect(c1, r1, 150, 100);
// c.stroke();


// wait for 3 seconds and then load the yellow box


            c.fillStyle = "yellow";
            c.fillRect(c1+50, r1+50, 150, 100);
}
}

</script>

Comment: Thanks for that, it does take me in the correct direction. Now, in trying to understand this and running it in debug mode I seem to be unsure on the processing logic in the way this works. Would you be able to tell me how the control flow of the program actually works with setTimeout(function() {displayRects = true},3000);?

Comment: Hi Again, tried this, and the issue is that all I see is the blue color come up:
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var displayRects = false;
draw();
displayRects = true;
var pass = 1;
//while (pass < 3){
color(pass);
draw();
pass = pass+1;

color(pass);
//}


//setTimeout(function() {displayRects = true},3000);



function draw() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);

 }

Comment: function color(pass){

 if (displayRects && pass == 1) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(100,100,50,50);
 }

 setTimeout(draw, 3000);

 if (displayRects && pass == 2) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(150,150,50,50);
 }

 setTimeout(draw, 3000);

}